# Highlighting the selected Item in WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

my question seems to be an easy task but somehow all the things I tried won't give me the desired result.

In my MainWindow I have a ContentControl that binds to a variable called "CurrentView", which is a ViewModel. I switch the CurrentView via a Navigationbar.
In my first View there is a  DataGrid. When I click on an element on that DataGrid the Row gets highlighted in Blue and the selected Item gets saved in my ViewModel.

When I now jump to a new View, and back to the first View the selected Item is still selected in the DataGrid, but the Row is not highlighted…

I tried so many Things but somehow I can't get the Row Highlighted.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to focus the `DataGrid` for the selected row to become highlighted by default. You could for example call the `Focus()` method of the `DataGrid` in a `Loaded` event handler for the view that you are navigating to:

```
public partial class View1 : UserControl
{
    public View1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (s, e) => dataGrid1.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your Idea. Ist the same Approach as 
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=ArtikelGrid}"
somehow this doesnt work.

Comment: Okay i think u helped me there. I noticed that the Row is highlighted, but since the Colums are generated dynamically in Code behind, the Cells dont get highlighted, since somehow they get generated after the Row getting the Focus... Im onto something

Comment: Please read [this blog post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/11/08/how-to-programmatically-select-and-focus-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid-in-wpf/). It explains everything you need to know about highligting cells in a `DataGrid`.

Comment: Thanks for the Link. I had read that Artikel before. I think i found my Problem. I didnt think of it before, but in the moment where the DataGrid gets its item selected, the Datagrid doesnt have any colums. Thats why there are no Cells with Focus. I think with that knowledge i can fix my problem now.

Comment: I got a solution that is working, but only when i change the selected item from code. It is not working when the item that i choose from code is already the selected one.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you need focus on the specific row.
I use this behaviour:

using System.Windows;
   using System.Windows.Controls;
   using System.Windows.Input;
   using System.Windows.Interactivity;

```
namespace blaa
{
class DataGridRowBehavior : Behavior<DataGridRow>
{
    public static bool GetIsDataGridRowFocussedWhenSelected(DataGridRow dataGridRow)
    {
        return (bool)dataGridRow.GetValue(IsDataGridRowFocussedWhenSelectedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsDataGridRowFocussedWhenSelected(
      DataGridRow dataGridRow, bool value)
    {
        dataGridRow.SetValue(IsDataGridRowFocussedWhenSelectedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDataGridRowFocussedWhenSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsDataGridRowFocussedWhenSelected",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(DataGridRowBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsDataGridRowFocussedWhenSelectedChanged));

    static void OnIsDataGridRowFocussedWhenSelectedChanged(
      DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow item = depObj as DataGridRow;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            item.Selected += OndataGridRowSelected;
        else
            item.Selected -= OndataGridRowSelected;
    }
    static void OndataGridRowSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow row = e.OriginalSource as DataGridRow;
        // If focus is already on a cell then don't focus back out of it
        if (!(Keyboard.FocusedElement is DataGridCell) && row != null)
        {
            row.Focusable = true;
            Keyboard.Focus(row);
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Usage:

```
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="local:DataGridRowBehavior.IsDataGridRowFocussedWhenSelected" Value="true"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: I never worked with behaviour so far. I was Looking for a small fix